# replace a string inside a html5 <script>

Tags: javascript, html

like it's mentioned in the title i'm willing to replace a string inside a script tag `<script>`. what i want to replace is the string //WRITE by something else.

```
<script name="general" id="general" type="text/javascript">
some code
//Write
</script>
```

So i automatically tried :

```
ch="new string";
document.getElementById("general").replace('// WRITE',ch);
```

But i got the following error : Uncaught TypeError: Object `#<HTMLScriptElement>` has no method 'replace'.
So i understand that unlike `<div>`, `<script>` doesn't use that method. Is there an equivalent method ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think if you do this, bad things will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object returned by "getElementById" is a [DOM Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element) so you can change its contents by assigning to the [`innerHTML` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML):

```javascript
var general = document.getElementById("general");
general.innerHTML = general.innerHTML.replace('//WRITE', ch);
```

Be careful about your replacement token - your sample "script" tag uses the literal string "//Write" whereas your attempted regular expression will look for "// WRITE", which does not exist.  You must use the same literal string if you want this to work.j

**[Edit]** Note that scripts as defined per your example are run immediately when the browser loads the page so trying to modify them with another script will likely not have any impact.  Moreover, this strategy will not work if you try to modify a script that would occur later in the page because the browser will not have loaded it so there will be no element with the target id.  One possibility is to modify a function that is defined so it can be called later but this also might not work.  A better strategy for including dynamic content in a JavaScript block is to have the JS itself seek information in the DOM instead of the other way around.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the original script will run regardless (though that does not make any difference with commented-out lines)

Comment: @Pumbaa80: yes, good point.  I'll update my answer with that info.

Comment: What if the code to replace is inside a function ? would that make any difference?

Comment: @MarouaGasmi: it won't matter since the function has already been defined when you attempt to replace its contents.  The more I think about it, the more I think that modifying script source as such will have no effect whatsoever, since the source has already been interpreted by the browser by the time to attempt to modify it.

Comment: well i'm supposed to change the script then call on it from a button, is there any other logic to do that ?

Comment: @MarouaGasmi: yes but it depends on how, specifically, you want to change your program behavior.  I suggest creating a new, separate question which describes your situation more clearly.

Comment: yep that's what i should do. Thank you very much for your answers and explanations

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments above, the intention is to change a script at runtime.

Note that once a script has run, there is no way to "un-run" it. So you'll have to take care and possibly revert the effects manually.

You can create a second script and run that:

```
var oldScript = document.getElementById("general");
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.innerHTML = oldScript.innerHTML.replace('// Write', '// whatever');

// here comes the crucial part:
// insert the new script into the head element; this triggers execution
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
headhead.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
```